# Proxypass Apache only if port in host

Tags: node.js, apache, proxypass

I have a node app working on port 1234. Because I don't want the port number displayed anywhere, I have a ProxyPass rule in my Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPass /node http://example.com:1234
  ProxyPassReverse /node http://example.com:1234
</VirtualHost>
```

It's working perfectly: when I enter http://example.com/node in my browser, the expected page displays.
When I enter http://example.com:1234, too, but I don't want that URL to display in my browser. That's why I put a javascript to change window.location if there is "1234" in the URL...

That's not a good solution, because the page has to load before being redirected and the user sees the port number. I'd like to know if it was possible to redirect immediately example.com:1234 to example.com/node with an Apache rule. I searched all the documentation, but the solution isn't obvious...

Comment: What you should do is set up your node app to listen on 127.0.0.1, that way `example.com:1234` will work *only* from the localhost - i.e. it will be invalid for any external visitors to the site

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I didn't mention that the user comes to my app after having logged in through SSO, the SSO redirecting the user to the ":1234" host. I can't change that because I don't have the hand on the SSO.

Comment: Move node app to another port; Have another VirtualHost (`*:1234`) with `Redirect / http://example.com/`

Comment: If I do that, when I launch my node app, it says the port is already in use. :(

Comment: Actually @DusanBajic your answer was correct. Can you publish it so that I can vote you up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change SSO redirect URL, I would suggest the following:

1. Run your application on different port (for example 1235)
2. Create an additional VirtualHost listening on port 1234, and use it for redirecting to :80 with `Redirect / http://example.com/`
3. Modify your existing ProxyPass url to go to port 1235

Comment: To me more precise for those facing the same problem, my node app runs on port 1234, and the *:1234 VirtualHost has only one rule: redirect / http://example.com/node, the proxypass being left unchanged for *:80, but your comment helped me a lot!